# Is this scenario a bootleg ground? Is it safe? options?

Tags: grounding

I have a shop that has been fed a 3-wire (L1 - L2 - N)service years ago. The ground wires to the outlets are bonded to the neutral wires in the shop's subpanel. There is NO earth ground / ground rod at the shop. The outlets DO NOT have the ground wire hooked up at all, and no "typical" bootleg with a jumper or something. Should I hook up the ground wires in the outlets? I know the real solution is to run a separate ground wire from the source of the shop's service and turn the shop feed into a 4-wire with the separate bus for ground and neutral etc... But is it considered "bootleg" if I hook up the ground wires at the outlets like I said?

Comment: For each of: Service from main to subpanel **and** Wiring from subpanel to receptacles, is it *NM cable*, *wires inside metal conduit*, *armored cable* or *wires inside non-metal conduit*?

Comment: Wires inside non-metal conduit... 3-wire service is in plastic conduit. Then just just romex 3-wire going from the breaker box to all the outlets

Comment: Then this may not be so bad. Would it be feasible to run a green or bare ground wire through that conduit? If so, that would turn it from a 3 to a 4; then you would need to unbond ground/neutral in the subpanel. The Romex should have ground already, so that part is easy. I think...

Comment: @jackwarner -- can you post photos of the inside of the panel in question please? Or alternatively, with the upstream breaker off, what happens if you gently tug on one of the feeder wires exiting the conduit in the subpanel?

Answer (score 2):

> *The ground wires to the outlets...*
> ...The outlets DO NOT have the ground wire hooked up at all, and no
> "typical" bootleg with a jumper or something. Should I hook up the
> ground wires in the outlets?

First off, there are ground wires TO the outlets, but they are just sitting in there? That makes no sense and if the ground wires are there, you should connect them to the ground terminals of your outlets.

> *...are bonded to the neutral wires in the shop's subpanel.*

Secondly; is this a sub-panel or the SERVICE panel? The FIRST panel where the utility power comes in is the SERVICE panel, and you DO connect the Neutral and Ground wires together there. In a SUB-panel, you do not. If this is a sub-panel, then they should NOT be bonded (connected together), even though they are going to be at the Service panel upstream. The Service panel is where the Ground is then connected to the Grounding Electrode (ground rod) with a separate ground wire, called the Grounding Electrode Conductor (GEC). That should be the ONLY connection to ground in your building.

Thirdly, when talking about the number of "wires" in a service or cable, you do not count the ground conductors, it is not a "current carrying conductor" so is not considered a "wire". So "*Romex 3-wire going from the breaker box to all the outlets*" would mean 2 hot wires and 1 neutral, not 1 hot, 1 neutral and 1 ground. I'll assume you meant 1 hot, 1 neutral and a ground, which is called 2-wire NM cable with ground. NM cable is abbreviated by the size, the the number of current carrying conductors, then w/G if there is a ground wire, so for example 14-2 w/G is 14 ga, 2 wire (H+N) with Ground. The reason it is done that way is that you used to be able to get 14-2 with no ground, in which case it was just called 14-2.

Lastly, a "bootleg ground" is when there is NO ground wire run out to the receptacle box, so someone bonds the ground terminal of a grounded receptacle to the neutral terminal with a little jumper. That was technically legal up until 1969 but has not been since then. But from your descriptions, that's not what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the info and terminology. So then, This is a sub-panel. It's in a detached shop, btw. The outlet ground wires and neutral wires ARE bonded together in this sub-panel. The outlets in this shop have the ground wires run, but NOT hooked up at the outlets. So they are hooked up at the shared neutral / ground bus in the sub-panel, but left unattached at the outlet. Why, I don't know. If I hook up the ground wire at the outlet it seems like it is kinda a bootleg since the ground and neutral are bonded in the sub-panel. And yes, the Romex is 1 hot, 1 neutral, 1 ground.

Comment: It's my understanding (but I'm not an electrician) @jackwarner, is that a detached building _must_ have its own grounding rods. Before you go shopping, however, wait for an electrician to chime in on that.

Comment: NEC article 230.32 (A) is where the code requires that separate buildings supplied by feeders must have their own grounding electrode. The exception is when there is only one BRANCH circuit. You have a feeder circuit to the sub-panel. Connect the grounds at the receptacles, separate the grounds and neutrals in the sub panel, bond the round bar to the box and add a ground rod at the building with a GEC from the ground bar to the rod.. OR... call a licensed electrician and have them do it all for you ;-) Given the weird issue with the ground wires, there may be more problems than you know about.

Comment: The ground wire does not run back to the main service. It's a 3 wire sub-panel not a 4 wire (3-wire with a ground). If I disconnect the grounds and neutrals at the sub-panel, then if a HOT wire shorts to the metal chassis of a device where the ground wire is, it will try to get back to neutral through the earth which is not a good enough conductor. Right?